# Getting a display:none div to toggle (so that it displays) when a button is pressed, and then *stay* displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is set to display:none.

I have a button that, using jQuery code, displays the div.

I would like it so that when the user hits the button again, nothing happens -- the div just remains displayed regardless.

How can this be achieved?

The code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2AU/

JS:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
    Hello this is my div
</div>
<button id="myBtn">Toggle Div</button>
```

CSS:

```
#myDiv {
    background-color: red; 
    color: blue; 
    height: 50px
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use  $('#myDiv').show(); instead toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show `#myDiv` only, then replace `.toggle()` with `.show()` 
but if you want to show/hide, please use following code.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  if ($('#myDiv').is(":visible")) {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
  } else {
    $('#myDiv').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
  Hello this is my div
</div>
<button id="myBtn">Toggle Div</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  `.show()`

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').show();
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
    background-color: red; 
    color: blue; 
    height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
    Hello this is my div
</div>
<button id="myBtn">Toggle Div</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to this

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').show();
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eL2AU/13/)